# Visual Studio 2017 form

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day

I am developing a windows app form in VS2017 however i get the following errors
"Cannot assign to txtEmail because its a method group"

"EmployeeRquestFormUI.txtEmail() is a method which is not valid in the given context"

What could be the problem with the code: Please see code below

```
employeeRequestFormUI.txtJob_Desc = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
employeeRequestFormUI.txtEmail = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
employeeRequestFormUI.txtTelExt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
employeeRequestFormUI.txtRequestedBy = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
employeeRequestFormUI.radioLaptop = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
employeeRequestFormUI.radioDesktop = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
employeeRequestFormUI.txtDepartment = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
employeeRequestFormUI.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
```

Comment: Well, if `txtEmail` is a method, then what exactly are you trying to do by assigning a value to it?  Where is `txtEmail` defined?

Comment: If that is the exact error message you are getting I suspect it is because you have code someplace that includes the parenthesis in your call. Methods have parenthesis; properties do not.

Answer (score 0):

Look for

```
EmployeeRquestFormUI.txtEmail()
```

and remove the braces

```
EmployeeRquestFormUI.txtEmail
```

Comment: I have checked for EmployeeRequestFormUI.txtEmail and there is no braces

Comment: @user2941071 Just double click the compiler message.